# Install or connect Google Home to a third party "Action"

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I am developing an action using "Google Action". I have deployed the action as given in the [deployment documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/distribute/deploy).
Now I want other users to integrate or connect their Google Home device to this action. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

See the section [Confirm Your Deployment](https://developers.google.com/actions/distribute/deploy#confirm_your_deployment) under the page you have linked to. Your Action will be reviewed and, once approved, will be Deployed and available for others to use.

Until it has been approved, you can only let others test it using the same scheme you are using to test it.

Answer (score -1):

Pro Tip: You can deploy your action to the public by using https://01234567890.firebaseio.com/.json as your fulfillment endpoint.

Comment: We can use firebase as the service instead of Heroku or Google Cloud?

Comment: Yes! Any service that exposes a public http endpoint can be used to fulfill requests.